# A question about Lebesgue Integrals

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Suppose that $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of measurable real valued functions on $\Bbb{R^3}$ and satisfies

i) For any compact set $K \subset\Bbb{R^3},$ $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{K}{|f_n(x)|dx}=0.$$
ii) For any ${3 \over 2}\le p\le3,$ $$\sup_{n\ge1}{||f_n||_p<\infty} .$$
Then, Show that $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\int_{\Bbb{R^3}}{|f_n(x)|\over|x|^{3/2}} dx }=0 .$$

**my thoughts :**
I have my doubts about $3/2\le p\le3.  $ I think that only $ p=3/2,3$.

**proof.**
Let $ \epsilon >0.$ and let $ g_n(x)=|f_n(x)|/|x|^{3/2}. $

First, For $ \epsilon$ and any $ n$ $$\exists R>0 ; \int_{|x|>R} {g_n(x) dx<\epsilon.}$$
Indeed, $$ \int_{|x|>R} g_n(x) dx<\left[ \int_{|x|>R} |f_n(x)|^{3/2}\right]^{3/2} \left[ \int_{|x|>R} {1 \over |x|^{9/2}} dx\right]^{1/3} \;\;\; (by \;H\ddot o lder) $$ $$ <4M_{3/2}\pi \int_R^{\infty} r^{-5/2} dr \rightarrow 0\;\;(R\rightarrow 0). $$

Similarly ( change the role of two functions ) , we have $$ \exists \delta>0;\int_{|x|<\delta}g_n(x) dx<\epsilon.$$
therefore, (i) completes the solution of the problem.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Hint: Let $\epsilon>0$. It follows from (2) that there exist $\delta>0$ and $R<\infty$ such that the integral over $|x|<\delta$ and the integral over $|x|>R$ are both less than $\epsilon$ for _all_ $n$. Now the set $\delta\le|x|\le R$ is compact...